# How do I configure dbms_metadata to emit modified names from get_ddl?

Tags: oracle, plsql

For now, I'm using the following statement

```
DECLARE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN -- MAIN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', TRUE);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', false);

   FOR t IN (
        select object_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl(object_type, object_name, owner) AS gen_ddl
        from
        (
            --Convert DBA_OBJECTS.OBJECT_TYPE to DBMS_METADATA object type:
            select
                owner,
                --Java object names may need to be converted with DBMS_JAVA.LONGNAME.
                --That code is not included since many database don't have Java installed.
                object_name,
                decode(object_type,
                    'DATABASE LINK',      'DB_LINK',
                    'JOB',                'PROCOBJ',
                    'RULE SET',           'PROCOBJ',
                    'RULE',               'PROCOBJ',
                    'EVALUATION CONTEXT', 'PROCOBJ',
                    'CREDENTIAL',         'PROCOBJ',
                    'CHAIN',              'PROCOBJ',
                    'PROGRAM',            'PROCOBJ',
                    'PACKAGE',            'PACKAGE_SPEC',
                    'PACKAGE BODY',       'PACKAGE_BODY',
                    'TYPE',               'TYPE_SPEC',
                    'TYPE BODY',          'TYPE_BODY',
                    'MATERIALIZED VIEW',  'MATERIALIZED_VIEW',
                    'QUEUE',              'AQ_QUEUE',
                    'JAVA CLASS',         'JAVA_CLASS',
                    'JAVA TYPE',          'JAVA_TYPE',
                    'JAVA SOURCE',        'JAVA_SOURCE',
                    'JAVA RESOURCE',      'JAVA_RESOURCE',
                    'XML SCHEMA',         'XMLSCHEMA',
                    object_type
                ) object_type
            from all_objects 
            where owner in ('PAYTRAS')
                --These objects are included with other object types.
                and object_type not in ('INDEX PARTITION','INDEX SUBPARTITION',
                   'LOB','LOB PARTITION','TABLE PARTITION','TABLE SUBPARTITION')
                --Ignore system-generated types that support collection processing.
                and not (object_type = 'TYPE' and object_name like 'SYS_PLSQL_%')
                --Exclude nested tables, their DDL is part of their parent table.
                and (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from all_nested_tables)
                --Exclude overflow segments, their DDL is part of their parent table.
                and (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from all_tables where iot_type = 'IOT_OVERFLOW')
        )
        order by owner, object_type, object_name
            )LOOP       
                dbms_output.put_line(t.object_name || '###' ||t.gen_ddl);
            END LOOP;
    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
END; -- MAIN

/
```

Problem is, that I would want to use the generated DDL to be executed inside the same schema  and this would lead to naming collisions. I know of the transform parameters, but there I only know of a 1:1 mapping of names, so I would need to change the parameter before each call. Is there something like "rename_expr" to make names like 'originalname_suffix' to avoid collisions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know exactly what you need, but if it is about suffixes in ddl statements maybe this will give you some guidence.
Create cursor to collect owners, types and names of your objects, nest your ddl For cursor loop inside the explicite cursor loop and add suffixes to the names of objects using replace (or concatinations or both). You should adjust the code to your actual context. Comments in code, too.

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR c IS
      Select    owner, object_type, object_name
      From      all_objects
      Where     owner in ('YOUR_USER_NAMES_LIST') And 
                -- 
                object_type IN('PACKAGE', 'PACKAGE_BODY') And -- this is condition just for testing yours is below
                --not in ('INDEX PARTITION','INDEX SUBPARTITION','LOB','LOB PARTITION','TABLE PARTITION','TABLE SUBPARTITION')
                Not (object_type = 'TYPE' and object_name like 'SYS_PLSQL_%') And
                (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from all_nested_tables) And 
                (owner, object_name) not in (select owner, table_name from all_tables where iot_type = 'IOT_OVERFLOW')
      Order By  owner, object_type, object_name;
    --
    v_owner           VarChar2(32);
    v_object_type     VarChar2(32);
    v_object_name     VarChar2(32);
    --
    CURSOR c_ddl IS
      Select      dbms_metadata.get_ddl(v_object_type, v_object_name, v_owner) AS gen_ddl
      From        all_objects d
      Where       owner = v_owner And
                  object_type = v_object_type And
                  object_name = v_object_name;
    --
    v_counter   Number := 0;
    v_sfx       VarChar2(10);
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN -- MAIN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS_AS_ALTER', TRUE);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform,'TABLESPACE',false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SEGMENT_ATTRIBUTES', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'STORAGE', false);
    dbms_metadata.set_transform_param(dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'EMIT_SCHEMA', false);
    --
    OPEN c;
        Loop
            Fetch c InTo v_owner, v_object_type, v_object_name;
            Exit When c%NOTFOUND;
            v_counter := v_counter + 1;
            v_sfx := '_SFX_' || v_counter;
--  Here or within For Loop below you can manipulate different suffixes 
--  depending on conditions regarding object's owner/type/name and include 
--  some delimiters, if needed, to be used in Replace statement
            For t in c_ddl Loop
--  You could collect all original object's data with suffixed data here, too
                dbms_output.put_line('--  OBJECT TYPE = ' || v_object_type || ' |  OBJECT_NAME = ' || v_object_name || Chr(10) || 
                                     Replace(t.gen_ddl, v_object_name,
                                                        v_object_name || v_sfx) );
            End  Loop;
        End Loop;
    CLOSE c;    
END; 
/
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :  (for first object only)
--  OBJECT TYPE = PACKAGE | OBJECT_NAME = LOGGER

CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE "LOGGER_SFX_1" AS 
  PROCEDURE Init(xStatus OUT CLOB);
  PROCEDURE put_Log (mAPP VarChar2, mACT varChar2,  mUSR VarChar2, mTAB VarChar2 := Null, 
                     mTPK VarChar2 := Null, mMSG VarChar2 := Null, mCMND VarChar2 := Null, mORA VarChar2 := Null, RetMsg OUT CLOB); 

END LOGGER_SFX_1;
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE PACKAGE BODY "LOGGER_SFX_1" AS
--  
PROCEDURE Init(xStatus OUT CLOB)  AS
    BEGIN
        Declare

        Begin
            ...
            some code
            ...
        End;
    END Init;
--
PROCEDURE put_Log (mAPP VarChar2, mACT varChar2,  mUSR VarChar2, mTAB VarChar2 := Null, 
                   mTPK VarChar2 := Null, mMSG VarChar2 := Null, mCMND VarChar2 := Null, mORA VarChar2 := Null, RetMsg OUT CLOB) AS
    BEGIN
        Declare 
            RetMsg      CLOB;
        Begin
            ...
            some code
            ...
        End;
    END put_Log;

END LOGGER_SFX_1;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
*/
```